# Write a program with a loop that sums all odd digits of an input

Tags: loops, netbeans, input, sum

Hi I'm currently in school for Computer science and I'm having problems with two of my codes, the first one pertains to the title. I have to create a program that takes only the odd digits of an input and sums them. I honestly have no idea how to approach this, this is all I have

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    int a;
    int b;

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    a = in.nextInt();

    while (a > 0) { 
        if (a.charAt(0) % 2 != 0) {

        }
    }
```

the second problem I have trouble with is write program with loops that computes the sum of all square between 1 and 100 (inclusive) This is the code i have

```
    int i=1;
    int j=0;

    while (i<101){
      i = (i * i);
      j= (j+i);
      i++;
    }
    System.out.println(j);
```

Thanks, I've been searching through this book back and forth and found no ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I will not solve your home-work problem directly.
But it will give you an idea what to do

> Sum of all Odd numbers in given numbers

```
int sum = 0;
while(numbers are still there){
  if(presentNumber % 2 == 1){
     sum += presentNumber;
  }
}
```

and for second problem, if I understood correctly, Sum of Square Numbers which lies in 1 to 100

Logically, square root of 100 is 10. so all the square numbers which lies in 1 to 100 are 1 to 10 inclusive.

> That's sum of squares of 1 to 10 numbers (1^2+2^2+3^2+...+10^2)

```
int sum = 0;
for(int I=0;i<=10;i++){
   sum += (i*i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to approach the first option(odd / even numbers):

```
if ( x & 1 == 0 ) { even... } else { odd... } //This is because the low bit will always be set on an odd number.
```

or you can do something like:

```
boolean isEven(double num) { return (num % 2 == 0) }
```

Check [Check whether number is even or odd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342237/check-whether-number-is-even-or-odd) for more option.

Now about the squares check out [Fastest way to determine if an integer's square root is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer) for your answer

Comment: do we really need "Fastest way to determine ...". I think they are starter problems and bit of logic will do I guess :)