# I have an error in my Java program and I think it's a minor error but I don't know what to do?

Tags: java

```
do {
    input = scan.nextInt();
    //calculates minimum
    if (input < min) {
        min = input;
    }
    //calculates sum of even integers
    else if (input % 2 != 1) {
        sumeven = sumeven+1;
    }       

    //calculates sum of negative integers
    if (input < 0) {
        sumnegative += input;
    }
} while (input != 0);
```

So the program lets the user enter a series of inputs. The problem that I'm having, is when I type a number that's less than 0. The program is supposed to tell me how many even integers there are. So the issue is when the user types a sequence that's like:

> -1 -2 -45 -90 1 23 678 90 0.

The program will tell me that there's 3 even numbers. It doesn't count the negative numbers as even numbers for some reason?

Comment: did you strep through your code in a debugger to see what `input%2` evaluates to?

Comment: Why is there an `else` on your second `if`?

Comment: See also this prior question: [Mod in Java produces negative numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385024/mod-in-java-produces-negative-numbers)

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342237/check-whether-number-is-even-or-odd

Comment: Thank you so much! it was because of the else on the 2nd if. You made my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `else` in `else if (input%2 != 1)`. The else should be removed, otherwise the condition to increment the sum of evens is not reached if the input is less than min.