# I am getting a error of type mismatch from int to boolean

Tags: java, operators

The code is to check whether a number is even or odd using the last bit is 1 or 0.
if last bit is 1 it will go in if and print odd

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Even_or_odd {
    public void Check_even_or_odd(int a) {
        if(a&1)//error:Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean
            System.out.println("odd");
        else
            System.out.println("even");
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("enter a number to check even or odd");
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        Even_or_odd e=new Even_or_odd();
        e.Check_even_or_odd(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eran can you elloborate?

Comment: after adding   a&1==1 .                                                                                  I got the error Multiple markers at this line
 - Comparing identical expressions
 - The operator & is undefined for the argument type(s) int, 
  boolean

Comment: Basically, Java doesn't treat numbers as booleans, unlike c and some other languages which do. 0 or any number at all, is neither true nor false. You are doing binary & operation on two integers which ultimately result in an integer. Not boolean.

Comment: Change it to (a&1)==1. Must just be some confusion with precedences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code tests `a` for being odd/even by masking its binary representation with `1`, which has all bits set to zero except least significant one, which is set to `1`.

Odd numbers will produce `1` when masked with `1`; even numbers will produce zero. However, you cannot write `if (1)` or `if (0)`, because there is no implicit conversion from `int` to `boolean` in Java. You need to write

```
if ((a&1) != 0)
```

to fix this problem.

Comment: But still i dint understood why we need to write if ((a&1) != 0)

Comment: dasblinkenlight,so according to you while(1) would also not work in java?

Comment: @RushabhOswal That's correct. Both are C/C++ "tricks", while Java wants an explicit comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of binary operations, which is what I guess you are trying to do, check the input value using modulo:

```
if (a % 2 == 0) {
  System.out.println("even");
} else {
  System.out.println("odd");
}
```

In the condition block of the if statement you have to have a boolean value or an expression that evaluates to a boolean. `a&1` evaluates to an integer.

Also see [Check whether number is even or odd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342237/check-whether-number-is-even-or-odd)

Comment: I know the program using % opertaor,but i just want to highlight the same program using bitwise operator in java as it was bombarding errors.